# html tags inside xml tags - how access in javascript?

Tags: jquery, html, xml, ajax, dom

I'm passing my xml data through php where all xml nodes are contains html tags

```
<bccfalna-ad>
<ad-id>99</ad-id>
<ad-title>New Ad</ad-title>
<ad-code><u><b>C Language</b></u></ad-code>
```

when i access this code in javascript, its easily access ad-id and ad-title but it always print null for ad-code node

```
var edit_ad_id = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ad-id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
var edit_ad_title = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ad-title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
var edit_ad_code = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ad-code")[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML;
```

this above javascript code is used to access please help me to access html tags withing xml node....

Comment: I wouldn't have thought you'd need the childNodes[0] - var edit_ad_code = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ad-code")[0].innerHTML. However, I don't think you can use innerHTML on an XML object, you would have to get all the child nodes and loop through them, re-adding the tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should wrap the contend of your xml node with a CDATA block like this:

```
<ad-code><![CDATA[<u><b>C Language</b></u>]]></ad-code>
```

Comment: Happy to have helped you. Remember to mark as anwser the post that helped you.