# jQuery.get(): Trying to retrieve feed, but XML tags are lost

Tags: jquery, html, xml, rss, get

I'm using jQuery to automatically fetch the most recent post on a blog. jQuery.get() goes to the blog's RSS feed and returns the most recent post:

Here's what I'm using:

```
$.get('http://url.to/feed', function(feed) {data = $(feed).find('item:first').text(); $('#testbox').html(data);}, 'xml');
```

Here's the problem: That spits out just the text from the feed and the HTML elements. All the stuff like `<title>Title</title` is just stripped to `Title`. I need to keep all those XML elements intact so I can style things properly.

I've also tried `.html()` instead of `.text()`, but that doesn't work. Using neither one also doesn't work (i.e. `data = $(feed).find('item:first');`).

**How can I download and display a section of an RSS feed and not strip the XML tags?**
Thanks!

Comment: You say go to first item and return just the text in your function: `data = $(feed).find('item:first').text()`

Comment: @Chad yes, and I've had even less luck without it (and with .html). I mention that in the second-to-last paragraph.

Comment: But `$(feed)` refers to the XML tag, and you are saying to get the text of the node. Read about XML parsing with jQuery: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/xml-parsing-with-jquery

Comment: @Chad I know I am, but I don't want to. Is there some kind of a `.xml()` that I can use instead? Thanks!

Comment: @Chad thanks for the link, good info. However, I'm love to avoid parsing like that if I can. All I really want to do is spit it out with its tags intact so I can style them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hum... Take a look if your content can't just be wrapped with `<![CDATA[` and copied.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734912/html-tags-inside-xml-tags-how-access-in-javascript) (I know, CDATA abuse and everything, but OP don't want to parse the XML at all, just append it directly to the DOM).

**Update: What actually worked**

Change your call to the `get` method so it interprets the response as pure text and let JQuery create the DOM Tree for you. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675027/how-do-i-get-the-entire-xml-string-from-a-xmldocument-returned-by-jquery-cross-b).

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't change the code as it's auto-generated by the blogging website.

Comment: Does this mean you're trying to access a website outside of your domain/site with ajax?

Comment: @Jordan Yep. I'm working on a site that has a blog component, and I'd like to have part of the homepage show the most recent blog post. I know the request is working because it calls the success handler. And the data does come through.

Answer (score 2):

If you append it, it works.

```
$(feed).find('item:first > *').appendTo('#testbox');
```

Comment: @Gaby that throws `WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: DOM Exception 4: A Node was used in a different document than the one that created it (that doesn't support it)`. Any ideas?

Comment: @Nathan, what jQuery version do you use ?

Comment: @Gaby the latest, 1.6.0, linked from [Google's servers](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery)

Comment: @Nathan demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/CNYHM/1/ works fine even with older versions..

Comment: @Anthony Interesting, thanks for the link. As far as I can tell, that's for creating XML from a string. I can't even get the string. Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: @Nathan, are you using Safari? because indeed safari gives that error, but no other browser does..

Comment: @Nathan See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675027/how-do-i-get-the-entire-xml-string-from-a-xmldocument-returned-by-jquery-cross-b).

Comment: @Gaby Interesting, this works on the JSFiddle example but not on mine. Worth noting: In Chrome I get `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ngreensteintest.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` Does this mean I can't access the feed?

Comment: @nathan, Are you accessing it from the same domain ? (*and subdomain*) (*if you mean from jsfiddle then yes .. ajax requests are only allowed in same domain, unless jsonp*)

Comment: @Anthony That's more like it. Thanks!

Comment: @Anthony, you should edit your post and include that link, and @Nathan, you should accept his answer. more fair this way ..

Comment: @Nathan. Just for documentation purposes, have you gone with text dataType or `XmlSerializer`. @Gaby, can you update your answer to reflect what actually worked?

Answer (score 1):

Try returning the node, and not the text...

```
$.get('http://url.to/feed', function(feed) {
    data = $(feed).find('item:first'); 
    $('#testbox').html(data);
}, 'xml');
```

Comment: I have, without success. See the second-to-last paragraph.

Comment: Nathan... Is the returned XML [valid](http://validator.w3.org/)? Can you print it as a string to confirm that everything is being parsed correctly?

Answer (score 0):

How about trying something like this (It worked for me)...

Create a PHP file (get_xml.php) with the following:

```
$xml = file_get_contents($_GET['url']);
header("Content-Type: text/xml");          
echo $xml;
```

Then use the following jQuery:

```
$.get("get_xml.php",{url:'http://url.to/feed/'}, function(data){
    var data = $(data).find('item:first');
    $('#testbox').html(data);
});
```

Comment: No need for a proxy.. that is not the problem. The issue is merging nodes from different document owners.